# Trouble Understanding Government's Financial Databases

Tags: finance, data-request

What does the code field mean in [the state of Illinois's financial data](https://illinoiscomptroller.gov/constituent-services/local-government/local-government-division/financial-databases/?)?

[image: Snapshot of table AFRNotes from 2022 data]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Table UnitData, you can see that it appears to be a unique entity ID. To see this, I joined the distinct values of the the Table AFRNotes with the Table UnitData.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT AFRNotes.Code, UnitData.UnitName, UnitData.Description
    FROM AFRNotes INNER JOIN UnitData ON AFRNotes.Code = UnitData.Code;
```

Which gives the following results:

[image: join AFRNotes and UnitData]